# Why is Haskell unable to read "7e7" but able to read "7a7"?

Tags: string, haskell

Try to do:

```
Prelude> reads "7a7" :: [(Int, String)]
[(7,"a7")]

Prelude> reads "7e7" :: [(Int, String)]
[]
```

I tested this for all possible characters in the middle. They all work except for `'e'`. It seems as if [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) tries to interpret the number in scientific notation, but it can't because I'm asking for `Int`.

It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: I would consider this a bug as well.  If this is intentional, I would at least consider `reads` to be broken (much like `head` and other pure functions that can raise an error).

Comment: I'm not sure, but can easily imagine, that 7e7 is a representation for 7*10^7. Thus only an integer is found, no string.

Comment: @elias, you are right, see http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-190002.5

Comment: `reads "7e7" :: [(Float, String)]` returns `[(7.0e7,"")]`. I think it is a bug, `Read` instance for `Int` should not handle `e` specially like `Float`

Comment: As I expected. So... should I report this? Actually if Haskell does interpret 7e7 in scientific notation, why not simply return the integer? `70000000` is a valid `Int`.

Comment: @romeovs Yes, you should report it and include the information provided in my answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

GHC is indeed buggy. Its implementation of [`Numeric.readSigned`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Numeric.html#readSigned) uses the following:

```
read'' r = do
    (str,s) <- lex r
    (n,"")  <- readPos str
    return (n,s)
```

The `lex` call will try to parse any lexeme, and this means that for "7e7" it yields `[("7e7", "")]`, because "7e7" is a whole lexeme for a floating point literal. Then it tries to get a complete parse out of `readPos`, which in this case is an argument for which `Numeric.readDec` was passed in, and `readDec` will yield, correctly, `[(7, "e7")]` for the string "7e7". That fails pattern matching against `(n, "")`, and ends up as `[]`.

I *think* it should be simply as follows:

```
read'' = readPos
```

Comment: The `Read` instance for `Int` is defined in terms of `Numeric.readSigned Numeric.readDec`.

Answer (score 2):

`7e7 :: Fractional a => a` so it can't be read as an `Int`, but it can be read as a `Float` or `Double`.

```
ghci> :t 7e7
7e7 :: Fractional a => a
```

Comment: Ok I see why it should be read as an `Int` but for consistence should it not be read as a `7` with a `"e7"` as leftover (or what-chu-ma-callit), like with `"7a7"` for instance?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of GHC are you using?

Here is the (edited) output of a terminal session on my set-up:

```
GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> reads "7a7" :: [(Int, String)]
[(7,"a7")]
Prelude> reads "7e7" :: [(Int, String)]
[(70000000,"")]
Prelude>
```

There is an ambiguity here in how to interpret the input. 
Usually I imagine the interpretation of "7e7" as an Int of 70000000 would be perfectly acceptable. How is the compiler supposed to know to split the string after the first digit?

Comment: I'm using a newer verion: `GHCi, version 7.6.3`.

Comment: No, this output is wrong.  `reads "7e7" :: [(Int, String)]` should be `[(7, "e7)]`. Seems like GHC 7.4.1 had a different bug.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Thanks for your comment which has helped improve (I hope) my answer. I'm not sure if the output is 'wrong', though it is clearly not what was desired by the OP. I have edited my answer to try to clarify what I mean. The OP has hit on a situation where the compiler needs more information than it is given.

Comment: The way the Haskell Report defines this function means it should have the output I described. That's why I say this output is wrong.